# Swift 4 : Value of type NSString has no member 'count'

Tags: swift, xcode, count, nsstring

In viewDidLoad() I have :

```
let text = textField.text! as NSString
doneButton.isEnabled = (text.count > 0)
```

I get the error :

> Value of type NSString has no member 'count'

I don't understand since before swift 4 it was characters.count, now in swift 4 its announced .count directly, and I get this error.

Anybody ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `NSString` has `length`... (_violá:_ __[Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring)__ in Apple Docs) or use `String` in Swift directly and `characters.count` is still around.

Comment: You don't need to cast text to NSString here iguess. use direct rext as String and use count method.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys ;)

Comment: And again, please use if-let statement: `if let text = textField.text as? String { print(text) }`. App would crash on the first line if `textField.text!` is `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use `NSString` in Swift unless the compiler tells you.

Second of all the dedicated method to check for an empty string is `isEmpty`

```
let text = textField.text! 
doneButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
```

However – as pointed out by Leo Dabus – there is a smarter way (available iOS 10+)

```
doneButton.isEnabled = textField.hasText
```

Comment: UITextField has a property called hasText

Comment: Thanks for the property and unwrapping!

Comment: Thanks, @LeoDabus. I'm wondering why the `text` property is optional at all

Comment: Me too you can force unwrap it with no guilty

Answer (score 0):

NSString has no property count, please use length

```
print(text.length)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let text = textField.text! as String

if(text)
{
print(text.count)
}
```

Comment: This is bad, crash-prone, unsafe swift code. App would crash if `textField.text!` is `nil`. Use if-let statement: `if let text = textField.text as? String { print(text.count) }`